# hyperlink pivot tables in a list

Tags: excel, vba

i've got the code to scan the document and print all the names of the pivot tables with a hyperlink. but unsure about how to link it to the location of the pivot table.
here is the code:

```
Sub Button20_Click()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range
Dim pvt As PivotTable

Range("A1").Select

For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
 For Each pvt In sh.PivotTables
   ActiveCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
    "'" & pvt.Name & "'", TextToDisplay:=pvt.Name
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
  Next pvt
Next sh

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose the first cell of `TableRange2` as the `SubAddress`. That should be the top left cell of the pivot table. The `External:=True` argument creates the full address, including the sheet the pivot table is on:

```
Sub PivotHyperLinks()
Dim ListStart As Range
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim pvt As PivotTable
Dim i As Long

With ActiveSheet
    Set ListStart = .Range("A50")
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each pvt In sh.PivotTables
            .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ListStart.Offset(i, 0), Address:="", SubAddress:= _
                                       pvt.TableRange2.Cells(1).Address(external:=True), TextToDisplay:=pvt.Name
            i = i + 1
        Next pvt
    Next sh
End With
ListStart.Select
End Sub
```

I also modified the code to not use `Select` statements. They are generally to be avoided as inefficient (although they weren't doing much harm here). The links are still added to the ActiveSheet.

EDIT: I added back a final `Select` statement to take you to the beginning of the list of links.

Comment: You're welcome. Do a search on "Excel bullet points" and do what you want with the Macro Recorder turned on. Then look at the resulting code. If you get stuck ask for help here. Good luck.

Comment: hey is there a way to make the pivot table show up in the miiddle off the screen, or selecting the bottom row of the pivot table when clicking on the hyperlink instead of the top left corner.
guess its to do with " pvt.TableRange2.Cells(1). "

Comment: You're right. In order to select the last cell try: pvt.TableRange2.Cells(pvt.TableRange2.Cells.Count). Although I think that might do the opposite of what you want.